# machine when to sleep while updating, process seems stuck

Tags: suspend, software-updater

I let software updater do its thing earlier this morning, and the machine suspended after the ordinary 20 minutes. After having resumed, it's stuck on "preconfiguring packages," and the relevant processes don't seem to be using the CPU. Should I kill the process? Restart? Some combination thereof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it going to sleep had very little to do with getting stalled on "preconfiguring packages." I killed the process and investigated in Synaptic -- something seems to have been contracting itself in terms of dependencies, related to Python 3.3 and/or the replacement of Gwibber with "Friends." I'd be curious if others who had been using the dev branch of 13.04 up to now and installed the beta updates experienced the same issue, but in any case, I beat on it for a little while and then it installed updates just fine.